# Insert DATETIME into mysql databse using JSON/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, datetime

I have a database that contains an DATETIME column, I want to insert current date into it using JSON/PHP, but I kept having this error :

**Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php on line 13**
 And this is my php file

```
<?php
require("password.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", XXXX, XXXX, XXXX);
$driver_id = $_POST["driver_id"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$duree = $_POST["duree"];
$distance = $_POST["distance"];
$response = array();
$dt_obj = new DateTime($response['DateTime'], new 
DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); 
$dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')); 
$dt_obj->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
echo $dt_obj; 
 function AddRequest() {
    global $connect, $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance, $dt_obj ;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO demande (driver_id, pass_id, duree, distance, send_moment) VALUES (?, (SELECT user_id FROM passager WHERE email = ?), ?, ?, '$dt_obj')");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isdis", $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance,$dt_obj);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}

    $response["success"] = false;  

    AddRequest();
    $response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

And honestly ,I looked a lot for what letter should I use with datetime ex: "s" for string but I didn't find any.

Comment: you have 4 placeholders and 5 binds. That alone would have thrown you an error.

Comment: Oops ,I just copy it wrong , I'll rectify

Comment: I meant, you (still) have 4 `?`'s and 5x `isdis` parameters. `?, ?, '$dt_obj')")` should be `?, ?, ?)")`

Comment: yes 4 ? and $dt_obj is suposed to be the fifth

Comment: reload my comment up there; I edited to use the `?` instead of `$dt_obj`, you already used it in `...$email, $duree, $distance,$dt_obj)` <<

Comment: The fifth what?

Comment: I tried to leave it as you said, but I got the server's default time

Comment: See Gordon's answer then. If you have an issue with server's default time, then you'll need to set the time in a php directive instead. You're also overwriting the timezone declaration.

Comment: also; if your date column type is datetime, this `format('d-m-Y H:i:s')` failed. MySQL stores those as `YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00` - Just use MySQL's `NOW()`.

Comment: I have tried to change the server's default time , but since I'm using a shared one I found out that I cannot modify php.ini

Comment: You need to bind `$dt_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I know, that's what I told them in comments already, since they already have `"isdis", $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance,$dt_obj)` having `$dt_obj` as the last argument.

Comment: The error occures on line 13, which is `echo $dt_obj;`. The error message is crystal clear (IMHO). `echo $dt_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` would work. But other mistakes, mentioned by @Fred-ii- need to be fixed too.

Comment: Guys, I know it's a dumb question , but I'm a newbie, so please go with me in it , I don't have a column in my database  called ['DateTime'] , so it's predefined right !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error
>
> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in
> /storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php on line 13

This error occurs because of `echo $dt_obj` on line 13, but `echo` outputs one or more **strings**. You may want to use `var_dump($dt_obj)` or `print_r($dt_obj)` instead.

**EDITED AFTERWARDS**

```
<?php
require("password.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", XXXX, XXXX, XXXX);
$driver_id = $_POST["driver_id"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$duree = $_POST["duree"];
$distance = $_POST["distance"];
$response = array();
$dt_obj = new DateTime($response['DateTime'], new 
DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); 
$dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

/* create a DATETIME string to use in mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in line 24
*  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html */ 
$send_time = $dt_obj->format('Y-d-m H:i:s');

function AddRequest() {
    global $connect, $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance, $send_time ;
    echo($send_time);
    /* proper number of parametres (?) according to the db table's number of columns (5) */
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO demande (driver_id, pass_id, duree, distance, send_moment) 
                                           VALUES (?, (SELECT user_id FROM passager WHERE email = ?), ?, ?, ?)");
                                        
    /* http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isdis", $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance,$send_time);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}

$response["success"] = false;  

AddRequest();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: I replace it with : print_r($dt_obj) But I had this lines :DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-16 19:23:35.647985 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) 
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php on line 17

Comment: @AlMa Would you like to try to change your code like this?

    $send_time = $dt_obj->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    function AddRequest() {
        global $connect, $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance, $send_time ;
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO demande (driver_id, pass_id, duree, distance, send_moment) 
                                            VALUES (?, (SELECT user_id FROM passager WHERE email = ?), ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isdis", $driver_id, $email, $duree, $distance,$send_time);

Comment: Sir, I've tried your suggestion , well I got :  Notice: Undefined index: DateTime in /storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php on line 10 (To be honest I just copied these few lines of $dt_obj so I don't know really what is it) , as far for the insertion I got this 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Noticing that the column send_mement is of DATETIME type and $send_time is a string

Comment: Ok, try to change date format `$send_time = $dt_obj->format('Y-d-m H:i:s')`

Comment: Actually the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' works !! Thank you Gfour ,thanks Fred -ii- and all who tried to help me

Answer (score 2):

Don't insert the `datetime` value from the application.  Application level timestamps are troublesome, because of clock skew, time zones, latency, and so on.  Using the database server date time avoids these problems.

Set it based on the database datetime.  The simplest way is to default `send_moment` to have the current date time when a new row is inserted.  This is handled in the `CREATE TABLE` statement (see here).

If you are going to do it in a statement, I would recommend using `now()`:

```
INSERT INTO demande (driver_id, pass_id, duree, distance, send_moment)  
   SELECT ?, user_id, ?, ?, NOW()
   FROM passager
   WHERE email = ?;
```

Note that this slightly changes the ordering of the parameters.  The email is now the last parameter instead of the second.

I think the bind statement is:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isis", $driver_id, $duree, $distance, $email);
```

You'll have to double check on the types.

Comment: I was going to recommend `NOW()` also but their syntax was wrong and is the reason why it failed.

Comment: I keep having the same error, I think it's because of the last "s" in "isdis" I think because it refers to string, I s there another way to solve it !!

Comment: `SELECT ?, user_id, ?, ?,` I don't think the OP knows what to do with that; they'll think they can bind columns which can't be done, least that's what I get from this (pseudo) and they probably think so also. Unless that is some guru binding that I don't know about.

Comment: I think this too :/